# mkdir producing wrong folder name

Tags: bash, sh, mkdir

I have a problem using "mkdir" in my script file.

This is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir "wavlist"
cat 0160.121213.084834.log 0161.121213.085943.log 0162.121214.004916.log | grep .\.wav | cut -f 1 -d ' ' > wavlist/drills01.wavlist
```

whenever I execute this. The directory that it will create has a name "wavlist."

Why is there a "." at the end?

The output of bash -x

```
+ $'\r'
Drills01Commands_Celso.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
+ mkdir $'wavlist\r'
+ $'\r'
Drills01Commands_Celso.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
+ cat logfiles/0160.121213.084834.log logfiles/0161.121213.085943.log logfiles/0162.121214.004916.log
+ grep ..wav
+ cut -f 1 -d ' '
: No such file or directoryline 5: wavlist/drills01.wavlist
+ $'\r'
Drills01Commands_Celso.sh: line 6: $'\r': command not found
```

Comment: It should not. Something else is going on. Do you have other `mkdir`s in the script?

Comment: None. The script is just that short. I'm using cygwin.

Comment: What is the output of `bash -x script`? What is the output of `type -a mkdir`?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I cannot reproduce the behavior with Cygwin's coreutils v. 8.23. Maybe an update will help.

Comment: This is the output of bash -x script. @michas
    
    $ bash -x Drills01Commands_Celso.sh
    + $'\r'
    Drills01Commands_Celso.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
    + mkdir $'wavlist\r'
    + $'\r'
    Drills01Commands_Celso.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
    + cat logfiles/0160.121213.084834.log logfiles/0161.121213.085943.log logfiles/0162.121214.004916.log
    + grep ..wav
    + cut -f 1 -d ' '
    : No such file or directoryline 5: wavlist/drills01.wavlist
    + $'\r'
    Drills01Commands_Celso.sh: line 6: $'\r': command not found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you saved your script with windows line endings. That is why it complains about "\r".

Save with Unix line endings and try again.

The dot displayed by `ls` is actually the " \r" from the line ending.

Comment: Configure your editor to use the correct line ending. This depends on your editor. For example in `vim` you can set `:set ff=unix`. You can also use `dos2unix` to convert the file.